# Reading a config file which is placed on my Linux node in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read a config file using typesafe config library in Scala but I cannot place the conf file in my resource folder.

my `property/config` file is in below format

```
region=dev
numlines=2
```

and the name of the file is `property.txt`

the code looks as below

```
import com.typesafe.config._
val propertyFile = args(2)

val myConfigFile = new File(propertyFile)

val fileConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(myConfigFile)
val config = ConfigFactory.load(fileConfig)

val environment = config.getString("region")
val numberOfLinesToBeRemoved = config.getInt("numlines")
```

Answer (score 6):

Case 1 - Lets say, you have a sbt project then your config file `abc.conf` should be located at `src/main/resources/abc.conf`.

Now lets say that the file `abc.conf` has following content.

```
region=dev
numlines=2
```

Now, you can access these configs by,

```
import com.typesafe.config._

val confFileName = "abc"

val config = ConfigFactory.load(confFileName)

val environment = config.getString("region")
val numberOfLinesToBeRemoved = config.getInt("numlines")
```

Case 2 - If you can not include the conf file as a resource in your project, then you can use pass the conf file path as an argument to java command.

```
import com.typesafe.config._

val config = ConfigFactory.load()

val environment = config.getString("region")
val numberOfLinesToBeRemoved = config.getInt("numlines")
```

Now, you will have to pass the config file path while running the application as,

```
java -jar your_jar.jar -Dconfig.file=path/to/config-file
```

Case 3 - You want to use the config from some specified path

```
import com.typesafe.config._
import java.nio.file.Paths

// It should be absolute or full path
val confFilePath = "/home/your_username/something/abc.conf"

// just replace the above line by
// val confFilePath = args(2)
// and pass the full path as command line argument.


val confFile = Paths.get(confFilePath).toFile

val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(confFile)

val environment = config.getString("region")
val numberOfLinesToBeRemoved = config.getInt("numlines")
```

Comment: Thankd for this sarvesh. Is there anyway I can use below method                  `val propertyFile = args(2)
     val myConfigFile = new File(propertyFile)
         println("path is " + myConfigFile.getPath)
    val fileConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(myConfigFile)`   as a normal file and read it directly from that path?

Comment: updated. You just need to pass the full path in whatever way you want.

Comment: I tried the same and it says  "No configuration setting found for key 'region' " the command i used to run the jar is          `spark2-submit --class cargill.cdp.com.RMG.ScalaClass  testprogram.jar  "file:///efs/home/ps691026/emptyline.csv" "file:///efs/home/ps691026/output" -Dconfig.file="file:///efs/home/ps691026/propertydir/application.conf" `

Comment: Well... your file here is not a local file. The above methods will work only for files from local file system. Your file is a network file. You need add some code to download the file from the URI to some local path then use the `Case 3` method to load that file as Config. I am not sure if some easier and direct solution exists for your special case as this will depend on too many factors.

Comment: No I am running this on a local linux node and kept the file there itself in directory where jar exist

Comment: I tried taking the file:// out and it worked. However the other two files it does take with file:/// added to it . Anyway this works for me. Many thanks

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I am getting [error]  `object typesafe is not a member of package com import com.typesafe.config._` when I am trying to compile Case 1

Answer (score 0):

We can pass and load external configuration file by passing jar argument in spark submit command as well.(No need to copy config file in jar resources folder but need to copy on each node in cluster on same path)

```
    1] Spark command:
spark/bin>spark-submit --class test.Example Test.jar -appconfig /home/folderpath/APP.conf

    2] Example.scala:
    import com.typesafe.config._
    import java.nio.file.Paths
    ...........
    def main(argument: Array[String]) {
    var confPath = ""
    var argumentIndex = 0
    for (n <- 0 until argument.length) {
           if (argument(n).equals("-appconfig")) {
            argumentIndex = n + 1;
            confPath = argument(argumentIndex)
          }
    }
    val confFile = Paths.get(confPath).toFile
    val appConf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(confFile)
    name = appConf.getString("NAME")
    println("name : "+name)
    }
```